# Upload image, insert name and path in database based on value

Tags: php, image

I have the following code which works after submitting my form:
I'm getting the photo which is upload, in my upload folder.

Now I want to Insert this photo name and path in my database.

Example:
If image name is 6.jpg, I want in my database name=6.jpg and path=uploads/6.jpg

html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="foto">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
```

php:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit']) && empty($errors) === true )
 {
$name=basename($_FILES['foto']['name']);
$t_name=$_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$dir='upload';
if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
{
    
        
}
else
{
    
}
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(move_uploaded_file($t_name,$dir."/".$name))
{
     mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
     mysql_select_db('yourdb');
     $path=$dir."/".$name;
     $sql="INSERT INTO `your_table`(`name`,`path`) values ('".$name."','".$path."')";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);
     if($result){
         echo"Successfully added to db";
     }

}
else
{
     echo "Sorry.File Upload failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks,it works!

Now I want to display the uploaded image.. should I just echo the path?